# Hackerrank test cases fail even tho the output is right

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I can't figure out a hackerrank problem about numpy arrays.

> You're given a list with 9 ints (from 1 to 9) with spaces and you are supposed to return a reshaped 2d array containing those numbers with 3 columns and 3 rows.

Even tho the code I written seems to work fine for me in PyCharm, it doesn't pass the hackerrank test. I know I could just google the results and "ctrlc ctrlv" it, but I would like to know what exactly is wrong with my code.

```
import numpy
nums_list = []
num = input("Number: ")

for i in num:
    if i == " ":
        pass
    else:
        nums_list.append(int(i))
nums_array = numpy.array(tuple(nums_list))
nums_array = numpy.reshape(nums_array, (3, 3))
print(nums_array)
```

My code in PyCharm:

[image: my code in PyCharm]

hackerrank:

[image: hackerrank]

Comment: The hackerrank screenshot doesn't say that the input numbers are between 1 and 9. Where did that come from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the prompt on the input statement:

```
num = input("Number: ")
```

This puts `"Number: "` to stdout, failing your tests.

You can change it to `input()`, so there is no prompt printed, and then all the tests pass.

Note that your method of converting the input text into a list of numbers is not safe unless there are only numbers 0-9 present in the input data. Consider using this method instead, and skip the intermediate list/tuple:

```
>>> np.fromstring('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9', sep=' ', dtype=int)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code will fail if any input number is larger than 9, because you're processing each character separately.  Try entering "10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18".  You need to use `.split` to chop the input up into words, then convert the words.

Comment: I was going to say this, but the problem description says that the numbers are just from 1 to 9.

Comment: This is true, but it's not the reason for the failure of the test cases on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/np-shape-reshape/problem).

Comment: HIS problem description says that, but Hackerrank does not.  Thus, although my answer isn't the COMPLETE answer, neither is wim's.  Both fixes are required.

Comment: Actually, all 3 tests pass despite the OP's bug.  So I guess they haven't used any 2 digit numbers in their test cases.